# xUnit does not accept synchronous Throws with method that returns Task<>

Tags: asynchronous, tdd, xunit.net

I am writing a unit test for a method that returns a `Task<>`, but is not `async`. Still [xUnit.net](https://xunit.net) wants me to use `ThrowsAsync` to check for thrown exceptions:

> Error CS0619  'Assert.Throws(Func)' is obsolete: 'You must call Assert.ThrowsAsync (and await the result) when testing async code.'

The method returns a `Task<>` because it is an implementation of an interface, where some implementations do indeed run `async`.

This is the interface:

```
public interface IPtlCommand
{
    Task<PtlResult> Execute(string[] args);
}
```

and the implementation:

```
public class SetTag : IPtlCommand
{
    public Task<PtlResult> Execute(string[] args)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<PtlResult>(new PtlResult());
    }
}
```

my test code (that gives the compiler error):

```
[Fact]
public void SetTag_ThrowsArgumentExceptionWhenNoTag()
{
    var command = new SetTag();

    // act & assert
    Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => command.Execute(new string[] { "host" }));
}
```

other tests on the `command.Execute` call do work correctly, also without `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, it'll suggest a *Quick Action* to fix the issue. If you ask it to implement that suggestion, it'll change the test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task SetTag_ThrowsArgumentExceptionWhenNoTag()
{
    var command = new SetTag();

    // act & assert
    await Assert.ThrowsAsync<ArgumentException>(
        () => command.Execute(new string[] { "host" }));
}
```

This test now compiles (and fails, since `Execute` doesn't throw an exception).

Comment: I did that and it complained about the method not being `async`, and I thought it meant the called method, not the test method. Good thing I stopped yesterday ;-). It works now.